# Drawing as input for HIT on Amazon Mechnical Turk

Tags: javascript, mechanicalturk

I'm using Amazon's Mechanical Turk for the first time and am attempting to create a HIT that involves the worker submitting a drawing. I've created a test HIT using the below code, but received a message from a worker explaining they weren't able to submit it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">    </script><script src='http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js'>    </script>
<p>Imitate a painting with a landscape as its subject given the limiting drawing tool available. Intricate drawings will be rewarded a bonus!</p>

<div class="demo" id="colors_demo">
<div class="tools">&nbsp;</div>
<canvas height="500" id="colors_sketch" width="800"></canvas> <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function() {
          $.each(['#f00', '#ff0', '#0f0', '#0ff', '#00f', '#f0f', '#000', '#fff'], function() {
            $('#colors_demo .tools').append("<a href='#colors_sketch' data-color='" + this + "' style='width: 10px; background: " + this + ";'></a> ");
          });
          $.each([3, 5, 10, 15], function() {
            $('#colors_demo .tools').append("<a href='#colors_sketch' data-size='" + this + "' style='background: #ccc'>" + this + "</a> ");
          });
          $('#colors_sketch').sketch();
        });
      </script></div>

<form action="submit">This is a drawing of:<br />
<input name="drawingof" type="text" value="" />&nbsp;</form>
```

Aside from the issue of not being able to submit, will a drawing someone creates on the above canvas be saved/carried over when they submit? Or, alternatively, do I need to come up with a method that involves saving a file and uploading/emailing?

Any suggestions for methods of having workers submit drawings are very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify if you *must* use this particular library, or if you're open to any that can work well with MTurk? I looked at the docs for this library, and it appears that it will create an image file but doesn't seem to make it easy to get what you want, which is an array of values (or some other JSON-type representation). If you're open to other drawing/canvas tools, I can help to research a few and come back with ideas. That work?

Comment: I'm open to anything at all, certainly not tied to this library. As you said, any thing that works well with MTurk is perfect. Essentially the easiest way to allow someone to draw and submit their drawing. Thanks very much!